# I am New to nodejs and trying to update a category in categories table but it is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

### >     I am trying to update a data using updateOne method but i am not able to debug it why it is not working ?

```
   router.post('/edit-category/:slug', async (req,res) =>{
    // res.send(req.body.id);
    try{
        const updatedPost =  await Category.updateOne(
            { _id:    req.body.id},
            { 
                $set: { title: req.body.title }, 
                $set: { slug: req.body.slug } 
            }

            );
        // updatedPost.update((error) => {if(error){console.log("hiiiiiiiii"+error)}});
        res.send(updatedPost);
        // console.log(updatedPost);
    }catch(error){
        console.log({message:error})
    }

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. Check in DB whether the document is there in DB with `req.body.id` as `_id`
2. Try for the below code:

   `const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
   const updatedPost =  await Category.updateOne({ _id:    ObjectId (req.body.id)}`

Comment: i got  message: ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined

Comment: i fixed the error but still the data is'nt updating

Comment: yeah it gave me 5e12ed3df41ae92b6c13f1cf

Comment: @ PRATIK M VYAS Did you check in DB data is there with the above id

Comment: @PRATIK M VYAS That you her to check in your frontend code. Whether you are connecting to different DB?? Also how do you checked?? Through GUI?? or terminal command??

Comment: GUI mongodb compass

Comment: @PRATIK M VYAS Now you have to check from where its coming.. For the question what you have posted , I think you got the answer

Comment: @PRATIK M VYAS Accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: @PRATIK M VYAS If you didn't post your frontend code its very difficult to guide you regarding this. Also can you post your query how did you checked in comment section??